# String to Int for calculations, then back to String?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a string variable called tbSKUPrice. I need to convert this into an int to take 10% off it, then output it as the new number in a string.

I'm a beginner when it comes to this, so this may be way off. But I'm using this code:

```
int OldPrice1 = parseInt(tbSkuPrice);
// I plan on putting calculations here
OldPrice1.text = OldPrice1.toString();
```

I can't even output the number at the moment. I'm using AS2. Could anyone offer advice?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to refer to two different things using the same variable name.

If you have a textbox cllaed `OldPrice1`, then you're going to have to choose a *different* name to refer to the integer as.

Answer (score 1):

```
parseInt('tbSkuPrice')
```

`tbSkuPrice` does not contain any valid number, so of course it cannot be parsed correctly. What you are probably trying is to use the *content* of the variable `tbSkuPrice`, so do this:

```
parseInt(tbSkuPrice)
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't mean to include those quotes. It doesn't work either way, thanks for the answer though.

Comment: What is the value of `tbSkuPrice`? Also check `OldPrice1` for `NaN`.

Comment: The value of tbSkuPrice is 2000. I'm not getting a NaN for OldPrice1 as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

First, an example that might work:

```
var inputPrice:Number = parseInt(tbSkuPrice); // could also use parseFloat()
var outputPrice:Number = inputPrice * 0.9; // or another calculation
outputPrice = Math.round(outputPrice * 100) / 100; // rounding to two decimals
outputTextField.text = outputPrice.toString(); // explicit toString()
//or 
outputTextField.text = ""+outputPrice; // implicit toString
```

Then some comments. Don't reuse variables if the types differ. It's easier if you strongly type your variables, cause the compiler will give you a nudge if you try to bend the rules. Next, name your variables starting with a lowercase letter. Read up on [some coding guidelines](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions), they are your friends if you ever need to revisit your code, or pass it on to someone else.

Cheers, EP.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric-Paul, very useful info. Will do.